# Simple Paypal IPN integration in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a wordpress site with paypal button integrated.  It works as expected.  I want to use IPN to do the following after a successful payment:

1) Send Email to buyer
2) change the user role in wordpress

Question is how do I embed a standalone PHP file in wordpress which will be called by IPN and has access to wordpress functions ?

Comment: I'm actually just about to release "[PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://bitbucket.org/angelleye/paypal-ipn-for-wordpress)" that will make configuring IPN and extending it to automate things very simple.  It's done now.  Just wrapping up final testing and I'll be releasing it within the next few days for sure.  You could look at the code in that project to see how the IPN listener is configured for WordPress and do it yourself, or just wait 2 or 3 days and use it when it's done.  :)

Comment: Thanks this will be very useful.  What is the name of your plugin?

Comment: The name of the plugin is PayPal IPN for WordPress.  I will be releasing it very soon.

Comment: Here  I wrote an article to integrate paypal easily on your wordpress site without using plugins. http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/08/paypal-ipn-listener-wordpress-without-using-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Ideally what you want to do is add a stand alone file in your theme root e.g. ipn.php, in it call wordpress core functions.

put this at the top of the ipn file.

```
<?php require_once("../../../wp-load.php");?>
```

now you can get all wordpress functions inside.

Comment: This would work, but I have to disagree that it would be ideal.  The correct "WordPress way" to do it would be with a custom plugin or function in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: yes. but you have to be able to pass an actual URL to paypal to run the IPN

Comment: Right, that's not a problem.  You just register a function in your plugin to be trigger when a particular URL is hit.